# Update a commercial theme via Git

Tags: wordpress, git, wordpress-theming

I design wordpress themes which many private clients buy and install themselves on their own servers. If I update the theme is there a way for users who have installed the theme to be notified that there is a new version available and then install the new version via the wordpress admin. Exactly like how updates for themes hosted at wordpress.org are treated.

Is it possible to do this with git somehow? Does anyone have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. You could provide your users credentials to your Git server, but I'm not sure how many webhosts have Git preinstalled on their servers.

Comment: Have you tried [any of the Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+auto-update+commercial+theme)? Nothing usable?

Comment: Git would have to be installed on the user's box, the user would have to have a github account, you'd have to build an interface and/or very smart algorithm to handle any potential conflicts, commits, etc... I can see the utility here, but it would probably be faster/easier to build a script that downloads and overwrites the old theme. All you'd need there is a button and ftp creds from the user.